# A Locus problem

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

> Two fixed points $A(p, q)$ and $B(r, s)$ and a fixed line $L: ax + by + c = 0$ are given. A variable point $P$ moves on the plane such that $AP$ intersects $L$ at $C$ and $BP$ intersects $L$ at $D$. What is the locus of $P$ if $CD$ is a fixed distance $d$?

My attempts at this are the following.

Take $P$ as $(h, k)$. Write the equation of the line in its parametric form. Name $C$ as $(f, g)$. Then in usual notation $D$ is $(f + d \cos\theta, g + d \sin\theta)$. Now using the formula for the area of a triangle (the determinant one), I set area of $APC$ as zero and area of $BPD$ as zero.

I cannot proceed further. Please help how to avoid the hairy algebra after this step or if there is any alternate better solution.

Comment: With @Ernie060's setup I get $(s-1)xy+(d-r)y^2+(-ds-d+r)y+ds=0$.

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer, @Jan-MagnusØkland. I must admit that I didn't checked the calculations myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation will become easier if you first apply an isometry. First apply an isometry such that the line $L$ will be the $x$-axis (i.e. $L: y=0$) and such that the point $A$ lies on the $y$-axis (i.e. $A=(0,q)$). I also think you may apply a dilation, so in fact you can assume that $A=(0,1)$.